# Unzip/zip ipa file causes install problems

Tags: windows, macos, sign, ipa

I have been wrestling with resigning an iOS app (ipa file) provided by a third party. As documented in many other places I am following the process:

- unzip
- copy embedded.mobileprovision
- codesign
- zip

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. The same file will load sometimes and not others. In trying to isolate the problem I have simply unzipped the ipa, then rezipped it. The new ipa file is slightly different to the original but everything inside the original and the new ipa is identical. When I try to install the new ipa file it fails with:

Could not install application on device. Error: A signed resource has been added, modified or deleted.

Looking in the console log of the device I get the following messages:

- iPad1 installd[843] : 00403000
  verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620393
- iPad1 installd[843] : 00403000
  preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at
  /var/tmp/install_staging.VEviVe/BlahBlahBlah.app
- iPad1 installd[843] : 00403000
  install_application: Could not preflight application install
- iPad1 mobile_installation_proxy[876] :
  handle_install: Installation failed

Given that nothing inside the ipa file has changed, which is where I thought all the signing information was, why won't the rezipped file install?

Some more info, the error above occurs installing the rezipped ipa file using the iPhone Configuration Utility running under Windows. The rezipped ipa file installs using iTunes but gives the following errors in the console log for the device:

- iPad1 installd[918] : entitlement 'aps-environment' has value
  not permitted by a provisioning profile
- iPad1 installd[918] : entitlement 'application-identifier' has
  value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Comment: I have rerun these tests on a MAC running iPhone configuration Utility and the ipa file always installs. Looks like the problem is related to the Windows version of iPCU and I guess how it internally unzips the ipa file before it is installed.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in iPCU on Windows. If I add the ipa file the application fails to install. However if I unzip the ipa file and add the .app directory then it installs OK.